# Margin: 0 auto и полоса прокрутки.

Tags: html, прокрутка, css

На сайте страницы выравниваются по центру с помощью margin: 0 auto;
Есть длинные страницы, у них справа полоса прокрутки, у коротких нет.
В результате при переходе с длинной на короткую страницу и наоборот сайт дёргается.
Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: А не пробовали использовать собственный скролл? Который можно и контроллировать и поверх контента красиво расположить.

Без замены можно предложить разве что поставить overflow: scroll у страниц - тогда скролбар будет и у коротких страниц.

Привели бы работающий пример - можно было бы что-то более конкретное предложить.

Comment: Гадкий контакт как-то выкручивается со стандартным, спросить бы у них..   
А будет ли собственный скролл нормально на мобильных всяких работать?

Comment: @Dazar, вконтакте есть два блока с класами `scroll_fix` и `scroll_fix_wrap`, ширина первого считается с помощью скрипта при загрузке и изменении размера окна. За счёт этого и не дёргается

Comment: @Dazar, именно собственный скролл помог на мобилках.

"Собственный" - имеется ввиду не нативный. Мы использовали [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). В нем, правда, есть свои косяки, но среди всех опробованных вроде как он пока был лучшим.

Хотя может быть для наших задач он был лучшим, а для ваших может оказаться лучшим другой.

И точно не помню, но вроде как на WinPhone он косячно работает.

Comment: @Crasher, вот это мне даже больше подходит... правда пока только в общих чертах представляю, как это сделать...

Comment: оказывается этот вопрос задавали уже два раза...  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/79543. 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/173583. 
решение там есть, а я для себя решил прикрутить красивый скроллбар. всем спасибо.

Comment: Если в magin указывается две цифры, то первая - гороизонт, вторая вертикаль, т.е. `margin 0 auto` означает `margin 0 auto 0 auto` т.е, 0 однозначно слева и ноль справа. А сверху и снизу - возможно будут дургие значения, не помню что значит auto. Возможно как раз auto и приводит к тому что страница "дергается".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Принудительно задать странице отображать скроллбар вообще всегда, не зависимо от высоты контента:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```